# Merge Two package names in one

Tags: android, google-play

I have two standalone apps with different package names `com.example.x` and `com.example.y`
in the same account. I did that for a marketing purpose and now i want to merge them in one app also merge the two statistics of the two apps (installs, reviews,..etc).
How can i do that without losing users ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't , no body does that . you may update your application and put a message to your users that this version is no longer maintained and that they have to install the new version , you may also add a button that sends an intent to the play store app to redirect your users to the new version .